# Does using reaver crash or bring down a network

Tags: wifi, password-cracking

Does using [Reaver](https://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/) crash or bring down a network?

I've googled this and haven't turned up anything. I mean like a home router.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "bring down", and what you were doing with reaver that caused this? We can make educated guesses about what you mean, but better if it's explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: Also: what kind of network? Your $50 home router, or the entire Amazon Cloud Services network?

Comment: Page 8? https://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf

Comment: No this tool is not designed nor have i heard of it bringing down a network maybe using the tool from multipul computers at the same time it may be able to. Also as stated below services will usually restart when they crash. I remember testing a netgear router against upnp exploit everytime there service crashed it would automatically restart due to another program monitoring pid obtained from pid file. I would assume the program running wps such as hostapd if it crashed it would restart aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

Home-router firmware is notoriously fragile, so any sort of sustained attack (or sometimes, even ordinary activity) can cause it to crash, requiring a reset.

Answer (score 2):

Reaver *could* crash a home router, depending on a few factors. However, if we assume the implementation of WPS was well written (that is, didn't leak memory or suffer race conditions), it is unlikely that reaver would cause a crash.

The attack leveraged by reaver involves brute forcing the WPS Pin.  Depending on how well the router firmware was written, the attack may exhaust resources or corrupt memory. You are likely performing an operation that the developers did not explicitly intend to handle.

As Schroeder mentioned in the comments, the paper [Brute forcing Wi-Fi
Protected Setup](https://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf) written by [Stefan Viehböck](https://twitter.com/sviehb) notes the following on page 8:

> In rare cases devices started to send malformed messages or their web interface and routing did not
>   work properly anymore. A reboot was needed to solve the problem. This might be evidence of some
>   kind of corruption, but was not investigated further.

Although it does not appear that a comprehensive study suggesting which devices would crash under such an attack is available, most devices would likely be fine. It is most likely that even if a problem did occur, a simple reboot would be enough to restore the original functionality.

If you are considering testing equipment used in production, it would be wise to do so outside of peak hours.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, no, the attack only tests for the AP's response to stimuli. But, the developers have [noted](http://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf) that some home-grade firmware dies when the Reaver attack was used.

A successful brute-forcing does not change the settings, so the existing users of the network are not aware.